# Storing special characters in MySQL 5.6

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8, special-characters

My application accepts a variety of characters in MySQL database. 
One such example is:

```
ã ã‚Œã§ã‚‚ç°¡å˜ï¼Twitterè‡ªå‹•ã¤ã¶ã‚„ãè¨­å®šãŒã§ãã‚‹ã‚µã‚¤ãƒˆï¼AutoTweetï¼ˆã‚ªãƒ¼ãƒˆãƒ„ã‚¤ãƒ¼ãƒˆï¼‰! CH1J2tthG6 å®šæœŸçš„ã«ã¤ã¶ã‚„ãbotã‚„URLã®å®£ä¼ã«ã‚‚ä½¿ãˆã¾ã™ï¼ 2318999869;
```

Could you please recommend what COLLATION should I use to store such values? 
By default MySQL uses `latin1_swedish_ci`, which I believe will not store these characters correctly.

My purpose is to only fetch such characters and not use them for sorting. So performance tweaks are highly recommended.

Thanks!

`

Answer (score 1):

Not a "Collation" problem; rather it is a "Character set" problem.

Probably you

- had utf8-encoding of your text when you INSERTed it -- where did the data come from?, and
- had `SET NAMES latin1` (or equivalent) -- What kind of code did you use for the INSERT?  What version of MySQL *were* you using?, and
- stored the bytes into a column declared as `CHARACTER SET latin1` -- Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Assuming that all matches, then the solution is first to fix the data via the 2-step ALTER mechanism to convert the latin1 column to utf8 without altering the bytes.  It is described [in my CHARSET blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#2_step_alter).  (The specifics of the `ALTERs` depend on `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)

(If they don't all match, the I need to dig further.)

After that, there may (or may not) be an issue with how you are SELECTing the data to get it out.  Be sure to have `SET NAMES` set to the encoding (utf8 or latin1) that you need for your output.

**Edit**

Hmmm... I don't recognize most of those characters as being the regular mangling, so let's dig further.